# Inverse Laplace transform, rank1 correction of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Given real-valued vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{u}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, is there a nice expression the inverse Laplace transform of  $f(y)$ below?

$$f(y)=\frac{\left(\sum_i \frac{u_i}{y-a_i}\right)^2}{1-\sum_i u_i \frac{u_i}{y-a_i}}$$

If nice formula for $g(t)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}[f]$ is not possible, I'm interested in a nice upper bound on $g(t)$ which works for my application. I have $a=-2u(1-u)$ and $u$ represents a discrete probability distribution over $d$ outcomes (entries of $u$ are positive, adding up to 1)

---

Motivation:

$f(y)$ is the Laplace transform of $g(t)=\langle \exp(t(A+B))-\exp(tA),\mathbf{1}\rangle$ where $A$ is diagonal matrix with $\mathbf{a}$ on diagonal and $B=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T$ is rank-1. Inverting this Laplace transform gives a method to compute rank-1 correction to matrix exponential and matrix power.

Mathematica [seems](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-exp-rank1-correction.nb) to discover simple formulas for $g$ for specific values of $\mathbf{a}$,$\mathbf{u}$, I'm looking for a more generic expression. In my application, $\mathbf{a}=-2 \mathbf{u} (1 - \mathbf{u})$ while entries of $\mathbf{u}$ are strictly positive and adding up to 1.

For instance, it tells me that

$$L^{-1}\text{[f](t)=}-1. e^{-0.495868 t}+0.112202 e^{-0.423048 t}-1. e^{-0.396694 t}+0.0556054 e^{-0.317963 t}-1. e^{-0.297521 t}+2.83219 e^{-0.0441126 t}$$ when

$$\mathbf{a}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{60}{121} \\
 -\frac{48}{121} \\
 -\frac{36}{121} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\mathbf{u}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{6}{11} \\
 \frac{3}{11} \\
 \frac{2}{11} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Obscure. If $a$ is a vector , what is the meaning of $v? $ If $a$ is a number then $f(y)=\frac{C}{y^2(y-a)(y-a-u.v)}$ is a rational function to be expanded in partial fractions. Remember that $\frac{1}{(y-a)^k}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x(y-a)}x^{k-1}dx/(k-1)!.$

Comment: Almost impossible to understand which are the constants, what is the variable taking the role of Laplace variable $s$ ?... In particular, what is $v_i$ ? $v_i=\frac{u_i}{1-a_iy}=\frac{u_i}{1-a_is}$ ??

Comment: Moreover, your pointer points to a graphical document devoided of any information... Too few is too few !

Comment: Edited post for clarity. There's just one variable, $y$, and the rest are provided constants. Expanded section on the background of where this comes from

Comment: What is $\frac{1}{1-\mathbf{a}\,y^{-1}}$ when $\mathbf{a}$ is a *vector*?

Comment: Pointwise division, 1 is vector or ones or scalar 1 depending on context

Comment: Notation depending on context. I luv it. Is $\frac{\mathbf{u}}{1-\mathbf{a}\,y^{-1}}$ the vector with elements
$\frac{u_i}{1-a_i\,y^{-1}}\,?$

Comment: Stephen Boyd calls it "enlightened notation" :) I've changed to index notation to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks! What is enlightening to some is obscure to some others :)

Comment: Obscure motivation. $M=e^{A+B}-e^A$ should depend on some real variable $x$ if you consider its Laplace transform. And what is $1$? a vector of $R^n$? a matrix $(n,n)$? How do you define the scalar product between $M$ and the vector or  the matrix ${1}$?

Comment: Was missing variable $t$ in motivation, fixed. I define $\langle x, \mathbf{1}\rangle$ to be the sum of all entries in $x$. So $\langle \mathbf{v}(x), \mathbf{1}\rangle$ is a sum of entries in vector and $\langle \exp(tA), \mathbf{1}\rangle$ is a sum of entries in a matrix

Comment: @GérardLetac expansion through partial fractions is what Mathematica seems to be doing, added a concrete example it solved for $d=3$. For something like $d=1000$ it takes too long to get a solution. Checking for alternative methods in this [book](https://www.siirt.edu.tr/dosya/personel/laplace-siirt-2019320222328704.pdf), perhaps something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iAMK.png)

Comment: $f(y) = [\sum_i u_i/(y-a_i)]^2/[1-\sum_i u_i^2/(y-a_i)]$ is equivalent to the expression given for $f$, right?

Comment: It does appear to be equivalent!

Comment: I have no proof of this, but numerical analysis suggests the poles of $f$ are always real.

Comment: @eyeballfrog interesting. I've also tried few examples in Mathematica, and it always simplifies $f(y)$ to a form of Heaviside [formula](https://planetmath.org/heavisideformula), with all real roots

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, $f(y)$ is a rational function of $y$ of the form $p(y)^2/[q(y)r(y)]$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, $q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and $r$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are exactly the $a_i$. So ultimately it's going to end up partial fractioning out to a Heaviside formula. The problem is that the roots of $q$ aren't simple to find. As mentioned, they seem to always be real, but I have no proof of that.

Comment: Hmmm... We have discussed $\langle e^{-t(A+B)}, 1\rangle$ to some extent before (though for some reason you chose to stop all communication there. I don't know the reason but I apologize if I was too impatient or arrogant, so if you are willing to accept this apology and are in the mood of continuing, I'll be happy to do it :-) ).  Now you want to figure out the excess over pure $\langle e^{-tA}, 1\rangle$, right? That may be a bit trickier, though, of course, the upper bound from that thread still works. How bad is it in your simulations? (once you implement the $\lambda$ part, that is ;-) ).

Comment: Replied on MO, and your solution there was great for the original problem posed. This question was motivated by [linear recurrence](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-rank1-recurrence.nb) in the case where $d$ could be on the order of trillions. I was assuming $d=\infty$ and looking for analytic solution, since $O(d)$ numeric solution is too slow

Answer (score 1):

If we do the partial fraction decomposition of your Laplace transform we get:

\begin{eqnarray}
f[y]&=& - \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{y -a_j} + \frac{\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{d-1} {\mathfrak B}_\xi^{(d)} y^\xi}
{\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^d {\mathfrak A}_\xi^{(d)} y^\xi} \\
&=& - \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{y -a_j} + \sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{d-1} \frac{{\mathfrak B}_\xi^{(d)}}{{\mathfrak A}^{(d)}_d} \frac{y^\xi}{ \prod\limits_{\eta=1}^d (y - \zeta_\eta)} \\
&=& - \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{y -a_j} + \sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{d-1} \frac{{\mathfrak B}_\xi^{(d)}}{{\mathfrak A}^{(d)}_d} 
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^d \frac{(\zeta_\eta)^\xi}{y - \zeta_\eta} \cdot \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{\lambda=1,\lambda\neq \eta}^d (\zeta_\eta - \zeta_\lambda)}
\end{eqnarray}

where $(\zeta_\eta)_{\eta=1}^d $ are roots of the polynomial in the denominator in the first equation on the top.

Now, I took ${\bf a} = -2 {\bf u}(1- {\bf u})$ and, as you wrote, ${\bf u}$ being strictly positive and summing up to one and the roots seem to be distinct and always real, at least for $d=2,\cdots,5$, as seen from the code snippet below:

```
In[1407]:= 
d = RandomInteger[{2, 5}];
Clear[u];
ex = (1/(1 - Sum[u[i]^2/(y + 2 u[i] (1 - u[i])), {i, 1, d}])) Sum[
    u[i]/(y + 2 u[i] (1 - u[i])), {i, 1, d}]^2
ll = List @@ Apart[ex, y];


xi = Sort[
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, d - 1, WorkingPrecision -> 20], #1 < #2 &];
NSolve[(Denominator[ll[[-1]]] /. 
    Table[Rule[u[p], 
      If[p == d, 1, xi[[p]]] - If[p == 1, 0, xi[[p - 1]]]], {p, 1, 
      d}]) == 0, y]



Out[1409]= (u[1]/(y + 2 (1 - u[1]) u[1]) + u[2]/(
  y + 2 (1 - u[2]) u[2]) + u[3]/(y + 2 (1 - u[3]) u[3]) + u[4]/(
  y + 2 (1 - u[4]) u[4]) + u[5]/(y + 2 (1 - u[5]) u[5]))^2/(1 - 
 u[1]^2/(y + 2 (1 - u[1]) u[1]) - u[2]^2/(y + 2 (1 - u[2]) u[2]) - 
 u[3]^2/(y + 2 (1 - u[3]) u[3]) - u[4]^2/(y + 2 (1 - u[4]) u[4]) - 
 u[5]^2/(y + 2 (1 - u[5]) u[5]))

Out[1412]= {{y -> -0.452024347304020}, {y -> -0.421211866920340}, {y \
-> -0.1155609258393292}, {y -> -0.0254138465068981}, {y -> \
-0.00464339747974896}}
```

Then inverting the expression in the last equation is straightforward because ${\mathfrak L}^{-1}_y [ 1/(y+a)] (t) = e^{-a t}$.

###### Update:

The polynomial in the denominator in the right hand side reads:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^d {\mathfrak A}_\xi^{(d)} y^\xi = 
\prod\limits_{j=1}^d (y-a_j) - \sum\limits_{i=1}^d u_i^2 \prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^d (y-a_j)
\end{equation}
and ${\mathfrak A}_d^{(d)} = 1$ whereas the coefficients $\left({\mathfrak B}_\xi^{(d)}\right)_{\xi=0}^{d-1}$ read:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 B_0\to -a_1-a_2-\left(u_1-u_2\right){}^2 \\
 B_1\to 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
for $d=2$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 B_0\to a_3 \left(u_1-u_2\right){}^2+a_2 \left(a_3+\left(u_1-u_3\right){}^2\right)+a_1
   \left(a_2+a_3+\left(u_2-u_3\right){}^2\right) \\
 B_1\to -2 \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+u_1^2-u_2 u_1-u_3 u_1+u_2^2+u_3^2-u_2 u_3\right) \\
 B_2\to 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
for $d=3$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 B_0\to -a_3 a_4 \left(u_1-u_2\right){}^2-a_2 \left(a_4 \left(u_1-u_3\right){}^2+a_3
   \left(a_4+\left(u_1-u_4\right){}^2\right)\right)-a_1 \left(a_4 \left(u_2-u_3\right){}^2+a_3
   \left(a_4+\left(u_2-u_4\right){}^2\right)+a_2 \left(a_3+a_4+\left(u_3-u_4\right){}^2\right)\right) \\
 B_1\to 2 \left(a_3 u_1^2+a_4 u_1^2-a_3 u_2 u_1-a_4 u_2 u_1-a_4 u_3 u_1-a_3 u_4 u_1+a_3 u_2^2+a_4
   u_2^2+a_4 u_3^2+a_3 u_4^2-a_4 u_2 u_3-a_3 u_2 u_4+a_2 \left(a_3+a_4+u_1^2-u_3 u_1-u_4
   u_1+u_3^2+u_4^2-u_3 u_4\right)+a_1 \left(a_2+a_3+a_4+u_2^2-u_3 u_2-u_4 u_2+u_3^2+u_4^2-u_3
   u_4\right)+a_3 a_4\right) \\
 B_2\to -3 a_1-3 a_2-3 a_3-3 a_4-3 u_1^2+2 u_2 u_1+2 u_3 u_1+2 u_4 u_1-3 u_2^2-3 u_3^2-3 u_4^2+2 u_2 u_3+2
   u_2 u_4+2 u_3 u_4 \\
 B_3\to 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
for $d=4$.

For higher values of $d \ge 5$ those coefficients can be generated using the code snippet below:

```
d = 4;
(*Original expression*)
y =.; Clear[u]; Clear[a];
ex = (1/(1 - Sum[u[[i]]^2/(y - a[[i]]), {i, 1, d}])) Sum[
    u[[i]]/(y - a[[i]]), {i, 1, d}]^2

(*Discovered partial fraction decomposition*)
ex1 = - Sum[ 1/(y - a[[j]]), {j, 1, d}] +  
   Sum[BB[xi] y^xi, {xi, 0, d - 1}]/(Product[y - a[[j]], {j, 1, d}] - 
      Sum[u[[i]]^2 Product[y - a[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}] Product[
         y - a[[j]], {j, i + 1, d}], {i, 1, d}]);
MatrixForm[
 Simplify[First@
      Solve[CoefficientList[Numerator[Together[ex1 - ex]], y] == 0, 
       Table[BB[xi], {xi, 0, d - 1}]]] /. 
    a[[j_]] :> Subscript[a, j] /. u[[j_]] :> Subscript[u, j] /. 
  BB[j_] :> Subscript[B, j]]
```

[image]

###### Question:

Why is that inverse Laplace transform equal to that quantity that involves matrix exponentials? Can you explain it?

Comment: Thanks for in-depth response! Will dig into it a bit more, specializing to a case when $u_i=C* i^{-1.1}$, since that corresponds to what happens in neural networks. Regarding Laplace transform, see Lecture 9 [slides](https://ee263.stanford.edu/archive/expm.pdf) of Boyd, in particular [slide 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETIVu.png)

Comment: You can express matrix exponential as Laplace transform of a resolvent. Diagonal + rank1 has simple expression for resolvent because of Woodbury identity, probably special case of [generating function identity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282684/generating-function-for-abn-in-terms-of-generating-functions-for-an-b). Operation "add up all entries of the matrix" commutes with Laplace transform.

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: Interesting, so this is all the realm of autonomous dynamical systems. But you mentioned neural networks. Where is the connection to that topic then?

Comment: Training NN is equivalent to solving f(x)=b for non-linear function f. It's at least as hard as solving linearized system Ax=b. Estimate of $x$ after $t$ steps of gradient descent (GD) is $(I-A)^t x_0 \approx \exp(-t A) x_0$, hence it's equivalent to a dynamical system. For GD, A is diagonal, for SGD, it's diagonal minus rank1 matrix in question. I suspect that roots that you found are actually eigenvalues of that matrix